How to use a Johnson Matchbox Antenna Tuner with my Elecraft K3S?
I am experimenting with various antenna designs & feedlines and want to use a Johnson Viking Kilowatt KW Matchbox Antenna Tuner (250-30-3) with my K3S transceiver.  The Matchbox was designed to interface with a transmitter and receiver rather than a transceiver, so it includes relays and a connection block to work with them.  I have a 250-37 Directional Coupler ("DC") for the Matchbox.  The Matchbox has a 250-38 ammeter installed for tuning operations.
Other than tuning on a low power setting (e.g., 5-10 watts) and disabling the K3S' internal ATU, is there anything special I need to do to use the Matchbox with my K3S? I have Googled and have yet to find any discussions about this topic.
After reviewing the installation notes, it appears that the Matchbox's relay is set to receive mode by default. So, simply attaching 50-ohm coax from the K3S to the DC to the Matchbox will not make things work properly.  More connections are probably necessary.
Given the popularity of the K3S and Matchbox, I'd appreciate your help documenting the connections between these units or the reasons not to use this combination of technology today.
Thank you for your interest and time,
Mike


After reviewing the installation notes, it appears that the Matchbox's relay is set to receive mode by default. So, simply attaching 50-ohm coax from the K3S to the DC to the Matchbox will not make things work properly. More connections are probably necessary.

RX is the default state. Without modification the relay connections on the back have to be hardwired to 115VAC to make it work with a TRX. I don't know if or how long the relay inside the matchbox will last being energized all the time.
The transceiver is connected to the 50 Ohm input coaxial terminal. The external directional coupler is optional and would have to be placed in between transceiver and matchbox. The 3 wires (Fwd, Rev, GND) coming out from the coupler go to the corresponding terminals on the back of the matchbox.

What would be wrong with just using the RX port for the transceiver? Is the tuning element switched out in Rx?

@tomnexus - Two small inconviniences: The RX port has no coaxial terminal and is connected internally to the 300 Ohm tap. 50 Ohm loading will alter the matching range of the matchbox.

Thank you for your help, guys.  I will pull out my K3S manual to see what external connections it provides that may be able to drive the relay.  This matchbox is in pristine condition so I will not modify it.  I'd rather sell it to someone who can use it as designed.  I'll report back what I find.
On a related note...  If I do sell it, would you recommend building my own manual tuner or getting a commercial one?  I am not a huge fan of MFJ and Palstar, which really limits the field. :P

btw: I have been investigating alternative tuners at the following sites, which may help others.
https://www.dj0ip.de/antenna-matchboxes/symmetrical-matchboxes
https://www.theladderline.com/doublets-ladder-line-and-automatic-remote-tuners

I looked at the K3S' manuals and saw nothing that immediately seemed like a solution.  There is a receiver antenna port and it might be possible to create something attached to the transverter port.  Unless someone posts a direct solution, I think that I will try to find the tuner a new home where it will be used.
